Logging inside pydantic model/field validator
I'm trying to use model validator, to display a warning if two fields have certain value. So the code looks like this:
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: Int
    b: Int
    
    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def check_values(cls,data):
       if (data.get("a") == 2 and data.get("b") == 2):
           log.warning("both values set to 2")
           print("both values set to 2")

my_model = MyModel(2,2)

When i debug the code, i see that the condition is met and bof print and log instructions are reached.
However, i can't see the messages in stdin/err.
Is there a way to use validator to display/log those messages?

When I run this code, I can see both the log.warning and the print statement printed to the console

The issue likely lies in the configuration of the logging module. By default, Python's logging module does not output messages to the console unless a handler is set up to do so. Additionally, the default logging level may prevent the warning from being shown.
# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)  # Ensures WARNING messages are shown
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


Then why does the print not show anything?
